# Extending the solution of a PDE to the closure of the domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, differential-operators

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set. Suppose we know that the continuous function $u$ is a weak solution of
$$
Lu = 0
$$
on $U$, where $L$ is a second order linear differential operator with smooth coefficients on $U$. Also assume that $V\subset U$ is open and dense in $U$. If we know that $u$ is smooth on $V$, is it true that $u$ is smooth on $U$ as well? If not, what conditions do we need for this to be true?

Any reference to a text that talks about this will be much appreciated too.

Comment: Can you give me an example of $V\subset U$ that is both open and dense in $U$, and $V\neq U$?

Comment: @Jeff $U=(-1,1)$ and $V=(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$.

Comment: @Jeff complement of Cantor set

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was thinking about something else. It's certainly not true. You would need something like uniform ellipticity and smooth enough coefficients to make it true.

Comment: @Jeff As I mentioned, the coefficients are smooth on $U$. Can you give me a quick counter example?

Comment: $u=|x|$ is not a weak solution of $u_{xx}=0$. But there are counter-examples with non-constant coefficients, something like $x^2u_{xx}=0$. When $x\to 0$, weak solutions can have unbounded second derivatives.

Comment: @Jeff Oh I see. Thanks!